# How to create website endpoints based on search results?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, flask

I'm building a ReactJS website as part of a web dev bootcamp project.

I made a search feature using flask routes between the reactjs endpoints (../Language.js) and my Sqlite3 database.

> http://localhost:3000/kanjisearch

How do I make the result of a search into an endpoint itself though? For example if a user searches for "german verbs" the browser displays something along the lines of:

> http://localhost:3000/kanjisearch?=german+verbs

I want this so that when users hit the forward or back arrows on the browser, it takes the user to the previous search, NOT the previous page they were on.

Can I do this is react/javascript? Something else? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, you can use `react-router-dom` library
just do yarn add react-router-dom and create a route.js file and do the following

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import someScreen from "../somewhere" // this would be your Screen that you wanna show

const Routes = () => {
    return (
      <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/container/language/:language" component={someScreen} />
            </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  };

export default Routes;
```

after that you have to fix your app.js file as the following

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Routes from './router '; //the location of your router

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Routes/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

go to your component and do    `export default withRouter(someScreen)`

In your screen Since you have now a connected Class (to the routing) you can access match inside your props, this props is created by react-router and contains informations about what matched in this route : For exemple match.params.language would contains the :language from the route, meaning if u have /german+verbs

and now you can use the url like http://localhost:3000/container/language/german+verbs and then german+verbs

your parameters would be passed to your component as as

```js
match.params = {
    language: 'language+verbs'
}
```

use this is in your `compDidMount` method

Answer (score 0):

Well... what language do you want to use? :-) .  You can do it in any of those you mentioned.

Since you mentioned ReactJS first, you can do it in javascript by using the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/location) object. Just set and read the hash.  BTW the hash can be anything and is ignored by the browser, but your JS can look at it.  Your url would look something like this:

`http://localhost:3000/container/language/Language#search=german+verbs`.